# RecyclerView datas last row display with multiple time

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I don't understand why my recyclerview is only showing the last row of my database although I initialised it with 150 datas.
I searched a lot in the internet and even here on SO, but not one of the solutions is working. Can you help me to figure out why my recyclerView is only showing the last row of the database? Thanks in advance to all of you.

May be you can help me. Here is my code:

```
package com.example.frontaddress.matedesignc;
        import android.database.Cursor;
        import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
        import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
        import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
        import android.view.Menu;
        import android.view.MenuItem;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.widget.AdapterView;
        import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
        import android.widget.Spinner;
        import android.widget.Toast;
        import java.io.IOException;
        import java.util.ArrayList;
        import java.util.List;
public class Customer_Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private List<String> StateListArray =new ArrayList<String>();
    private List<String> StateList =new ArrayList<String>();
    private List<String> CityListArray ;
    private List<String> CityList ;
    private Spinner dropdown_state;
    private Spinner dropdown_city;
    private DBHandler DB = new DBHandler(this);
    private static final String BUSINESSNAME = "bussiness_name";
    private static final String MOBILE = "mobile";
    private static final String ADDRESS = "address";
    private static final String ID = "id";
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private Customer_list_Adapter adapter;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView_Customer;
    //ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_customer_list);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        GetStateList();    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_sub, menu);
        return true;    }
    public void CustomerDetails(String state,String city) throws IOException {


    try {
    List<customer_search_information> data = null;
    data = new ArrayList<>();
    customer_search_information current = new customer_search_information();
    Cursor RST_CSTInfo = DB.getRows("customer", "id,bussiness_name,mobile,address", " state='" + state + "' AND city='" + city + "'");

    while (!RST_CSTInfo.isAfterLast()) {

        current.bussiness_name = RST_CSTInfo.getString(RST_CSTInfo.getColumnIndex(BUSINESSNAME));
        current.state = state;
        current.city = city;
        current.address = RST_CSTInfo.getString(RST_CSTInfo.getColumnIndex(ADDRESS));
        String Mob = RST_CSTInfo.getString(RST_CSTInfo.getColumnIndex(MOBILE));
        current.mobile_no = Mob;

        current.e_mail = "mail.isigntech@gmail.com";
        current.id = RST_CSTInfo.getString(RST_CSTInfo.getColumnIndex(ID));
        // displayExceptionMessage(current.id+current.bussiness_name+current.state+current.city+current.address+current.mobile+current.email);

        data.add(current);
        RST_CSTInfo.moveToNext();

    }


        recyclerView_Customer = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.drawerListCustomer);
        recyclerView_Customer.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView_Customer.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView_Customer.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        adapter = new Customer_list_Adapter(this, data);
        recyclerView_Customer.setAdapter(adapter);


}catch (Exception e){ displayExceptionMessage(e.toString());}

    }
private void GetStateList()
{  Cursor Customer= DB.getRows("customer","state", " 1 GROUP BY state");
    while(!Customer.isAfterLast()){
        String state=Customer.getString(Customer.getColumnIndex("state"));
        StateList.add(state);
        StateListArray.add(state);
        Customer.moveToNext();
    }
    dropdown_state = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.SpnSrch_State);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Customer_Activity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, StateListArray);
    dropdown_state.setAdapter(adapter);
    dropdown_state.setPrompt("Choose State ");
    dropdown_state.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
            int item = dropdown_state.getSelectedItemPosition();
            String state =StateListArray.get(item);
            dropdown_city=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.SpnSrch_State);
            Cursor RstCity= DB.getRows("customer","city", "state='"+state+"' GROUP BY city");
            CityListArray =new ArrayList<String>();
            CityList =new ArrayList<String>();
            while(!RstCity.isAfterLast()){

                String city=RstCity.getString(RstCity.getColumnIndex("city"));
                CityList.add(city);
                CityListArray.add(city);
                RstCity.moveToNext();
            }
            dropdown_city = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.SpnSrch_City);
            ArrayAdapter<String> cityadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Customer_Activity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, CityListArray);
            dropdown_city.setAdapter(cityadapter);
            dropdown_city.setPrompt("Choose City ");
            dropdown_city.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {

                    int item = dropdown_state.getSelectedItemPosition();
                    String state =StateListArray.get(item);
                    item = dropdown_city.getSelectedItemPosition();
                    String city =CityListArray.get(item);

                    try {
                        CustomerDetails(state,city);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        displayExceptionMessage(e.toString());
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
                    displayExceptionMessage("Please Select State.");
                }
            });
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
            displayExceptionMessage("Please Select City.");
        }
    });
}

    public void displayExceptionMessage(String msg) {
        //TextView Txterror=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txterror);
        Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        if (id == android.R.id.home) {

            //  NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        }

        return super.onOptionsItementer code hereSelected(item);
    }

}
```

Here is my custom list adapter code:

```
package com.example.frontaddress.matedesignc;

        import android.Manifest;
        import android.content.Context;
        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
        import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
        import android.net.Uri;
        import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
        import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
        import android.view.LayoutInflater;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.ViewGroup;
        import android.widget.ImageView;
        import android.widget.TextView;
        import android.widget.Toast;
        import java.util.Collections;
        import java.util.List;
/**
 * Created by frontaddress on 10/08/17.
 */
public class Customer_list_Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Customer_list_Adapter.CustomerViewHolder> {
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Context contexts;
    List<customer_search_information> Cst_data = Collections.emptyList();

    public Customer_list_Adapter(Context context, List<customer_search_information> data) {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.Cst_data = data;
        // Toast.makeText(contexts, data.size(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        this.contexts = context;
    }

    @Override
    public CustomerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_search_staff, parent, false);
        CustomerViewHolder holder = new CustomerViewHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CustomerViewHolder holder, int position) {
    try {
    customer_search_information current = Cst_data.get(position);
        Integer  Pos=position;


    holder.TxtBisinessName.setText(current.bussiness_name);
    holder.TxtAddress.setText(current.address);
    holder.Statecity.setText(current.state + "-" + current.city);
    holder.Txt_Mobile.setText(current.mobile_no.toString());
    holder.TxtEmail.setText(current.e_mail);
    }catch (Exception e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(contexts,e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {



        return Cst_data.size();
    }
    class CustomerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        TextView TxtBisinessName;
        TextView TxtAddress;
        TextView Txt_Mobile;
        TextView Statecity;
        TextView TxtEmail;
        ImageView ImgPhoneCall,ImgMailTo;
        public CustomerViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            TxtBisinessName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Txtbusiness_name);
            Txt_Mobile = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.TxtMobile);
            Statecity = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Txtstatecity);
            TxtAddress = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Txtaddress);
            TxtEmail=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.TxtEmail);
            ImgPhoneCall = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ImgCallPhone);
            ImgMailTo= (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Imgmail);



            ImgPhoneCall.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    customer_search_information current = Cst_data.get(getPosition());
                    String  MOBILE = current.mobile_no;
                    try {

                        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(contexts,Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                         {
                            Toast.makeText(contexts, "Call Permission Not Granted ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            return;
                        }
                        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:+91" + MOBILE));
                        callIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        contexts.startActivity(callIntent);

                    }

                    catch (Exception e){
                        Toast.makeText(contexts,e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            });
           /*  TxtProfile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    customer_search_information current = data.get(getPosition());
                    String SID = current.id;
                    Intent intent = new Intent(contexts, StudentProfileActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("id", SID);
                    contexts.startActivity(intent);
                }

            });*/

            ImgMailTo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    try {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        customer_search_information current = Cst_data.get(getPosition());
                        String EMAIL = current.e_mail;
                        String BName = current.bussiness_name;
                        Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, EMAIL);
                        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "");
                        emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
                        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hi,"+BName);
                        final PackageManager pm = contexts.getPackageManager();
                        final List<ResolveInfo> matches = pm.queryIntentActivities(emailIntent, 0);
                        ResolveInfo best = null;
                        for (final ResolveInfo info : matches)
                            if (info.activityInfo.packageName.endsWith(".gm") || info.activityInfo.name.toLowerCase().contains("gmail"))
                                best = info;
                        if (best != null)
                            emailIntent.setClassName(best.activityInfo.packageName, best.activityInfo.name);
                        contexts.startActivity(emailIntent);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e){   }
                }

            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int ID=v.getId();
            customer_search_information current=Cst_data.get(getPosition());
            String SID=current.id;
            // Toast.makeText(contexts,"Item Clicked Profile: "+ v.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          //  Intent intent = new Intent(contexts, StudentProfileActivity.class);
           // intent.putExtra("id", SID);
           // contexts.startActivity(intent);


        }



    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is here , instead of

```
while(!RST_CSTInfo.isAfterLast()){

...
..

RST_CSTInfo.moveToNext();
}
```

try this ....

```
do(RST_CSTInfo.movetofirst()){

// your logic

}while(cursor.movetonext())
```

Comment: Hi Thank you for your suggestion. I try to step by step debugging and confirm all records are bind properly. Spinner have get records properly.